# Is is possible to fit an extra seat belt into a 1998 Suzuki Wangon R+?

Tags: suzuki, seat-belt

I have a Suzuki Wagon R+ from '98 and there are only 2 seat belts on the rear but space enough to accommodate at least 3 (skinny) people.

Can you recommend me any good practice advice on fitting an extra middle belt? What parts would I need to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Seat belts are anchored to the frame (not sure if you knew that), so in theory if you could find a lap belt that would be enough size, you would just need to drill two holes in the frame large enough for the seat belt bolts, spaced a decent width apart, and torque the bolts down to the spec of the other seat belt bolts in the rear. Not sure if you could route the belt between the seat cushions or what (I don't have a Suzuki Wagon), you may have to get creative.

This is all a hack of course since the lap belt didn't come by default, but I love hacking cars :-)

Comment: Be aware that adding a 3rd seat belt in your car is probably illegal. Check with your local police/law.

Comment: You'd also need to make sure those bolts are properly anchored. Simply drilling through won't be enough - at the very least you'll need spreader plates to stop the bolts pulling through the metal in the event of an accident.

Comment: Downvoting as simply "drilling a hole in the frame" and using the same torque spec as the other seat belt bolts is definitely not sufficient to ensure the strength and safety of the installation. A seatbelt is a safety device. This project should not be undertaken lightly.

Comment: @NickC you are definitely right, I should have included that but seat belts do have spreader plates, I was hoping that seeing the spreader plate with the seat belt would be sufficient, but with this I should have spelled it out.

Comment: @mac This was just a rough overview. Hopefully it goes without saying that caution should be taken, especially when adding seat belts. But, if the person is going to have a 3rd person in the back anyway, why not add a seat belt? My answer was given 'in theory', in practice a lot more planning and testing has to go into making structural changes to a car's frame. Nonetheless, I respect your dv.

Answer (score 1):

Its not the local laws but the federal laws you have to be concerned about.1) if in an accident you, not the insurance company, can and will be held liable for any and all damage to property and persons, 2)you wont be able to get insurance for it because you made modifications that have not been properly tested, 3) you wont be able to sell the car for the same reasons and you wont be able to get it inspected in quite a few states.

Comment: Answer is cool, but now you are assuming we all live in the US :)